# How to identify process based on the visible window?

Tags: window-manager, x11

On Unix/Linux there are some tools such as `xwininfo`, `xdotool`, `xkill` or `xprop` to [identify a window's PID by clicking on it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19161/21471), but they only work with X11.

Is there any similar solution for macOS? To get the process PID based on its visible window (e.g. once clicking on it)? Ideally invoked from the command line.

Comment: This might help. http://superuser.com/a/939476/4018